# How to modify the default LaTeX package parameters of Sphinx?

Tags: pdf, sphinx

I want to generate pdf by using Sphinx. Sphinx generates pdf through LaTeX. But I have to add `unicode=true` to package hyperref of LaTeX:

```
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
```

But Sphinx has generated a default `sphinx.sty` file that containing configuration of package hyperref when I ran `make latex`. I have to add `unicode=true` to this file every time after running `make latex` with Sphinx, then `make all-pdf` with latex to generate the pdf.

Is there any method to modify this parameter of package hyperref in the Sphinx's configure file, so that I can run `make latexpdf` with Sphinx to finish the two steps once?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

just add `\hypersetup{unicode=true}` to conf.py:

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': '''
        \\hypersetup{unicode=true}
     '''
}
```